# Which version of socketio java client is compatible with which version of flask-socketio server?

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I couldn't understand which version of socketio-java-client is compatible with flask-socketio server.

Whether I have to check the version of socketio-java-client version with the flask-socketio or python-socketio or to the python-engineio versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python Socket.IO documentation only tracks compatibility information against the JavaScript reference implementation and with the protocol version numbers. Unfortunately I do not have the time to test and update a compatibility table for every Socket.IO implementation that is out there.

What you need to do is find out with what version of the JavaScript reference implementation your Java client aligns with.

Or if you prefer, you can just test things out until it works. For the Python Socket.IO there are really two major versions that you need to test out.

First, try the latest one:

```
$ pip install --upgrade flask-socketio
```

If your client can connect, then you're done.

If not, try the older version:

```
$ pip install "flask-socketio<5"
```

If neither one works, you probably have some other problem that you need to sort out, unrelated to version differences.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,"What you need to do is find out with what version of the JavaScript reference implementation your Java client aligns with" Where can I find this?

Comment: From the maintainers of the Java package or their documentation, I would imagine.

Comment: That was very helpful. I can able to run socket client in web ios and android now...